# misalignment between the chart and the risk table in ggsurvplot

Tags: r, survival

I am observing an ugly misalignment between the chart and the risk table plotting with ggsurvplot of survminer package in R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt) -- "Angel Food Cake"

[image]

I would like to display (as the code has always done until a couple of days ago) survival chart and risk table perfectly aligned so that the year notches in the two axes coincide.

Comment: Can you share code and sample data to make this reproducible? Also, have you tried other solutions to align risk table and plot, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76897701/3460670) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736077/3460670)?

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with updates in the `scales`, `ggplot2` and/or `cowplot` packages. I would recommend updating all R packages you got to the newest version and trying this again.

If this doesn't help, you may want to check out the `adjustedCurves` package, which offers similar functionality.